# morphia mongodb retreive huge data batchwise

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I want to retrieve 200 000 data from db from mongodb using morphia.

Earlier I was using

> query.asList()

which gave me out of memory exception
I tried changing it to

> query.batchSize(50).asList()

but with no luck.

> **I update my code to**

```
Iterable<DataStreams> iterable= query.fetch();
            Iterator<DataStreams> iterator=iterable.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               dataStreamsList.add(iterator.next());                
            }           
           System.out.println("iteration done");
```

Comment: Please refrain from using non-English terms for orders of magnitude, as it may be unclear for wider audience what is “a data of 2 lakhs” — for example, 200 kilobytes do not seem too much.

Answer (score 2):

`query.asList()` will pull everything in to memory.  `query.fetch()` will return an Iterator allowing you to process each entity (in batches of 20 by default) without loading the entire result set in to memory first.

Comment: i have updated my question with my current code  as suggested by you in above question  , just to update after an hour i got again same exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space